# How to use array_diff for (.txt) files in PHP

Tags: php, array-difference

```
<?php
$new = array("12", "11", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4");
$old = array("10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1");

$result = array_diff($new, $old);

print_r($result);
?>
```

> ***The result is*** `Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 11 )` ***so*** `12 and 11`
>
> **According to this example how to use array_diff for (.txt) files in PHP**?
>
> Here are (.txt) examples:

*New (.txt) file*

```
Something here12
Something here11
Something here10
Something here9
Something here8
Something here7
Something here6
Something here5
Something here4
Something here3
```

*Old (.txt) file*

```
Something here10
Something here9
Something here8
Something here7
Something here6
Something here5
Something here4
Something here3
Something here2
Something here1
```

*Output (.txt) file*

```
Something here12
Something here11
```

Comment: Read the files into arrays, then use array_diff on them...

Comment: `array_diff(file('new.txt'), file('old.txt'));` That's all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reproduce your arrays from the text files :

```
<?php
$new = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('new.txt').PHP_EOL);
$old = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('old.txt').PHP_EOL);
$result = array_diff($new, $old);

$output= fopen("Output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach($result as $value){
    fwrite($output, $value.PHP_EOL);
}

?>
```

I am not sure if you wanted the strip the "Something here" but in your exemple output.txt it seems like not.

Comment: it gives different result :/

Comment: You don't need to add `PHP_EOL`, since `file()` includes the newlines unless you use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option.

Comment: @barmar But It doesnt the same output. The output should be 12, 11

Comment: @lou need to delete new line last of txt? PHP_EOL edd blank line at the end of the text. 
$fp = preg_replace('/^[ \t]*[\r\n]+/m', '', $fp);
$fp = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+$/', '', $fp);    these are doesnt work

Comment: @barmar how to use FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES php_eol edd new line at the end of text

Comment: @Andrew `$new = file_get_contents('new.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`